# unable to install Gensim with Python 3.5 on ubuntu

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, gensim

I am running a dockerfile on a ubuntu base image as follows :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt-get install -y python3.5 \
    python3-pip 

RUN apt-get install libav-tools -y

RUN apt-get update 

RUN apt-get upgrade

#RUN  apt-get install google-cloud-sdk

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip3 install pandas 
RUN pip3 install glob3

RUN     pip3 install --upgrade pip 
#RUN    pip3 install pandas 
RUN pip3 install glob3
#RUN    pip3 install json
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install fuzzywuzzy
RUN pip3 install gensim
```

I have python 3.5 installed on this machine, but still I am getting the error as follows :

```
Collecting gensim
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/bc/1415be59292a23ff123298b4b46ec4be80b3bfe72c8d188b58ab2653dee4/gensim-3.8.0.tar.gz (23.4MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-klg_2vmh/gensim/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-klg_2vmh/gensim/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-klg_2vmh/gensim/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-klg_2vmh/gensim/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        raise Exception('This version of gensim needs Python 2.7, 3.5 or later.')
    Exception: This version of gensim needs Python 2.7, 3.5 or later.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Is there some specific version of Gensim that i need to download or this is some different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `python:3.5`:

```
FROM python:3.5
RUN pip install gensim glob3 ....
```

that will save you a lot of space and steps ....

If you want to still using `ubuntu:14.04` then you need to use this:

```
apt-get install -y python-dev && python3.5 -m pip install gensim
```

since `python3.4` is the default on the `image`